# Is it possible to repair the camera of my Lumia 610 through Nokia Care?

Tags: lumia, camera

The camera of my Lumia 610 has a problem. It does not autofocus and the pictures are not taken clearly. Is it possible to change the camera through Nokia Care?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found about Nokia Care is that it is an extension of 12 months above the standard warranty you get. Here's what I've found on the site of *Nokia*:

> Nokia Care Protect extends the original Manufacturers Limited Warranty on your mobile device by offering repair and support for an additional 12 months.
>
> Nokia Care Protect helps you achieve peace of mind as your device remains under warranty with no hidden or additional fees. For one up-front price, Nokia Care Protect supports your maintenance and repair needs for an additional 12 months.

Please note that this is a **paying service** which you have to get **before** your standard warranty has expired!

It also provides a list of models for which they offer this service. Following **Lumia** devices are listed:

- 520, 525, 620, 625, 720, 925, 1020, 1320, 1520

Whether or not your device is supported. If it's still in warranty I suggest you go to the store where you bought it and bring it in for repair.

Answer (score 1):

Lumia 610s are prone to breakdowns and many with the same fault.  Try this

Scroll to the right side of the main screen in the app drawer and select Settings.
Scroll to the Applications and select Camera+Pictures.
Scroll down to the bottom and select Reset Camera.

If this doesn't work try a factory reset but as a last resort and make sure you back it up to your Microsoft live or outlook account.  If you don't have one, open one.

You should also consider is this.  The fault might be more than just the camera itself.   You can research online for the frequency of this fault and make notes. Then when you have a ton of examples go to Nokia a demand a repair as the product is not fit for purpose primarily being a camera phone, especially if you are in the UK.

Something else, if you have to send the phone away to be repaired or replaced under warranty or not, back it up. Because they may not transfer your data if they replace or repair the phone

Good Luck